# Accessing /dev/mem from GNU Radio on ZedBoard

Tags: c++, mmap, gnuradio

I'm trying to access a custom IP block from GNU Radio [ZedBoard] using /dev/mem. I tested the code routine writing and doing iterative reading from /dev/mem from a local c file. The code running directly from the console correctly sets the registers and reads the correct values back.

I made a custom GNU Radio block using this code but when executing the grc flow python script I receive the error that /dev/mem was not accessible.

I know that this is NOT a safe way to interact with the device and am working on a driver to replace this. Currently I need this to work for testing and development. I went so far as to change permissions to /dev/mem to 777, I added my local user (Linaro) to the kmem group as well. I execute the python file for the flowgraph using sudo as well.

What am I overlooking? Thank you.

edit: Adding  the output error is : "Permission Denied" if run from sudo after chmod 777 /dev/mem the error is : "Operation not permitted"

```
/* -*- c++ -*- */
/* 
 * Copyright 1970 <+YOU OR YOUR COMPANY+>.
 * 
 * This is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
 * it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
 * the Free Software Foundation; either version 3, or (at your option)
 * any later version.
 * 
 * This software is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
 * GNU General Public License for more details.
 * 
 * You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
 * along with this software; see the file COPYING.  If not, write to
 * the Free Software Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin Street,
 * Boston, MA 02110-1301, USA.
 */

#ifdef HAVE_CONFIG_H
#include "config.h"
#endif

#include <gnuradio/io_signature.h>
#include "qpskModulator_impl.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define READ 0
#define WRITE 1

#define SAMPLES 64
#define INPUT_WIDTH 32

int memmap_fpga(int direction, char * address, float value);

namespace gr {
  namespace fpga_accelerators {

    qpskModulator::sptr
    qpskModulator::make()
    {
      return gnuradio::get_initial_sptr
        (new qpskModulator_impl());
    }

    /*
     * The private constructor
     */
    qpskModulator_impl::qpskModulator_impl()
      : gr::block("qpskModulator",
              gr::io_signature::make(1, 1, sizeof(float)),
              gr::io_signature::make(2, 2, sizeof(short)))
    {}

    /*
     * Our virtual destructor.
     */
    qpskModulator_impl::~qpskModulator_impl()
    {
    }

    void
    qpskModulator_impl::forecast (int noutput_items, gr_vector_int &ninput_items_required)
    {
        ninput_items_required[0] = noutput_items;
        ninput_items_required[1] = noutput_items;
    }

    int
    qpskModulator_impl::general_work (int noutput_items,
                       gr_vector_int &ninput_items,
                       gr_vector_const_void_star &input_items,
                       gr_vector_void_star &output_items)
    {
        const float *in = (const float *) input_items[0];
        short *out0 = (short *) output_items[0]; // I CHANNEL
        short *out1 = (short *) output_items[1]; // Q CHANNEL

        short data_valid;
        const float BLANK = 0;
        float GO = 1;

    //int  hwI_mod[SAMPLES*INPUT_WIDTH/2];
    //int  hwQ_mod[SAMPLES*INPUT_WIDTH/2];
    int i;

    char * DATA_IN_ADDR = "0x43c00004";
    char * GO_ADDR = "0x43c00000";
    char * DATA_OUT_ADDR = "0x43c00008";
    char * DATA_VALID_ADDR = "0x43c0000C";

    // transfer input array and size to FPGA
    memmap_fpga(WRITE, DATA_IN_ADDR, *in);
    memmap_fpga(WRITE, GO_ADDR, GO); // assert go
    GO = 0;
    memmap_fpga(WRITE, GO_ADDR, GO); // reset go value

    data_valid = 0;
    while (data_valid == 0) {
        data_valid = memmap_fpga(READ, DATA_VALID_ADDR, BLANK);
        }

        // read the outputs back from the FPGA  
    unsigned temp_dataout;
    unsigned y;
     for (i=0; i < SAMPLES*INPUT_WIDTH/2 - 8; i++)
     {
     temp_dataout = memmap_fpga(READ, DATA_OUT_ADDR, BLANK);
        out0[i] = temp_dataout & 0xfff; // I channel
        y = out0[i] >> 11;
        if (y == 1)
            out0[i] = out0[i] - 4096;
        out1[i]  =   (temp_dataout >> 12) & 0xfff;
        y = out1[i] >> 11;
        if (y == 1)
             out1[i] = out1[i] - 4096;
        //printf("%d: HW: I_mod = %d and Q_mod = %d\n", i, hwI_mod[i], hwQ_mod[i]); 
    }

        // Do <+signal processing+>
        // Tell runtime system how many input items we consumed on
        // each input stream.
        consume_each (noutput_items);

        // Tell runtime system how many output items we produced.
        return noutput_items;
    }

  } /* namespace fpga_accelerators */
} /* namespace gr */

int memmap_fpga(int direction, char * address, float value){


    unsigned gpio_addr = strtoul(address, NULL, 0);

    /* DEBUG INFO
    printf("address: %08x\n",gpio_addr);
    if (direction == IN)
        printf("direction: IN\n");
    else
        printf("direction: OUT\n");
    printf("value: %d\n",value);
    */

    int fd;
    unsigned page_addr, page_offset;
    void *ptr;
    unsigned page_size=sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE);
    short temp_value;

        if (gpio_addr == 0) {
            printf("GPIO physical address is required.\n");
            return -1;
        }

    /* Open /dev/mem file */
        fd = open ("/dev/mem", O_RDWR);
        if (fd < 1) {
            printf("Couldn't open /dev/mem\n");
            return -1;
        }


        /* mmap the device into memory */
        page_addr = (gpio_addr & (~(page_size-1)));
        page_offset = gpio_addr - page_addr;
        ptr = mmap(NULL, page_size, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, page_addr);

        if (direction == READ) {
        /* Read value from the device register */
            temp_value = *((unsigned *)(ptr + page_offset));
            //printf("gpio dev-mem test: input: %08x\n",temp_value);
            munmap(ptr, page_size);
            return(temp_value);
        } else {
        /* Write value to the device register */
            *((unsigned *)(ptr + page_offset)) = value;
                munmap(ptr, page_size);
             //printf("Wrote to register\n");
        }


        munmap(ptr, page_size);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: you should add the *verbatim* error you're getting. Pretty sure this is unrelated to GNU Radio itself.

Comment: The program is printing out "Couldn't open /dev/mem" corresponding to this section of code. The reason I tagged it as a GNU Radio problem is that I only run into this issue when I call the code embedded within the Radio block.


`/* Open /dev/mem file */
fd = open ("/dev/mem", O_RDWR);
       if (fd < 1) {
            printf("Couldn't open /dev/mem\n");
            return -1;
       }`

Comment: @MarcusMüller IE if I run [this](http://pastebin.com/tpNjQzbK) I don't have issues. It is only when I run the same set of code embedded within the gnu radio implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

You open and memmap the same file for Read/Write access multiple times, without closing it in between – that's a recipe for disaster. Maybe you're just running out of file descriptors (there's a limit on that). Actually reading the `errno` (you **should** be doing that!!) would tell you the reason.

Then: Even opening *and* closing the file repeatedly is a bad idea, performance wise– just open and `mmap` it once in the constructor. There's no advantage reopening it constantly.

Comment: Thanks - I updated the code to close fd every read/write as well as making all the reads iterative in ONE session of file open.

As far as the other access problem is concerned the output I'm getting when running this from GNU Radio is:

`Couldn't open /dev/mem, Error: Permission denied`

Where Permission Denied is the `strerror(errorno)`

Comment: When I chmod /dev/mem to 777 and run the script again I receive the error : "Operation not permitted"